# Extract protein sequences from a GBK(GenBank) file without scripting

Tags: bioinformatics

How to extract protein sequences from a GBK(GenBank) file without scripting?
I know that writting a script using BioPerl or Biopython can do this, but it is not elegant and daunting to beginners and biology persons. Any thing like

```
$ SOME_PKG_MANAGER install PKG
$ CMD ab.1234.gbk > ab.1234.faa
```

Comment: Coding is definitely elegant but not un-daunting perhaps ;)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "it is not elegant". If scrolling through the file and copying and pasting sequences out is your version of elegant I'm not sure what the question is... Scripting languages like perl and python were made ***exactly*** for this situation. But [I can't see the biological question here](http://meta.biology.stackexchange.com/questions/3110/what-to-do-with-bioinformatics-programming-questions/3122#3122) so I'm going to flag as off topic.

Comment: Yeah I agree with Good Gravy. This is like asking "I want to do cell culture but I don't want to go through the process of changing media. Is there a robot that can do this for me?"

Comment: @WYSIWYG If there is, you cannot afford not knowing that. This is the value of my question.

Comment: @FrozenFlame Extracting sequences is not very difficult. Usually most people write their own scripts to do that. Packages are generally made to deal with more complex data extractions and computations. What you want to do can be done using a one liner code.

Comment: @WYSIWYG I know that extracting sequences is not a difficult task. But why waste time writing the same script again. If you can do it in one line, show me your code; that's what I want.

Comment: @FrozenFlame That is off-topic in biology. See the meta-post that Good Gravy mentioned.

Comment: @FrozenFlame I posted my answer previously (in Perl) and it would be trivial to convert it into a one-liner, but everyone jumped all over it in the comments because they thought you did _NOT_ want some code, and because I provided no instructions. Then Chris, a moderator deleted my answer. I guess you didn't see it in time. Oh right, as WYSIWYG mentions you cannot post answers that your so-called "peers" here have determined to be *off-topic*. Because being on-topic is so much more important than actually helping someone.

Answer (score 3):

My colleagues and I have recently published a toolbox of command-line utilities that are modeled after GNU Textutils (e.g. grep, cut, tr, uniq) called FAST: Fast Analysis of Sequences  ([cite](http://journal.frontiersin.org/article/10.3389/fgene.2015.00172/full)).

To install FAST you can use:

```
perl -MCPAN -e 'install FAST'
```

Or install the current development version from [github](https://github.com/tlawrence3/FAST). The FAST install comes with a cookbook, sample dataset and all utilities have `man` pages. The cookbook is also available on the github wiki.

To convert the features annotated in a genbank file to fastA sequences you can use `gbfcut`. Below are examples of using `gbfcut`:

To convert all annotated features of a genbank file to fastA format:

```
gbfcut genbank-file
```

Output only tRNA features:

```
gbfcut -k tRNA genbank-file
```

Output all feature sequences with a "note" qualifier containing "telomere":

```
gbfcut -q note=telomere genebank-file
```